# Adding costume role to user group in coginto user pool

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, amazon-iam, user-management

I am trying my hands on cognito with very little knowledge about it.

Here I am trying to create a user group that has a role attached to it.

[image]

There is no option to type in the ARN there is only an option to select from the drop-down.

My role is not present in the drop-down but I could see other customer roles that were created earlier.

Am I missing something?
Also would like to know the functions of the user group in cognito.

Could any one please suggest me on this

Comment: Can you check a rust policy of your role created? Maybe its incorrect, thus it does not show.

Comment: @Marcin Have made the change in the question by adding the trust policy

Comment: I checked on my account. It shows all roles. Maybe you have to refresh window? Just looking for any example how such user pool group role looks like, and can't find any :-(

Comment: @Marcin re-logging into the aws account worked. But really not able to find any use case or much information on the Cognito user group

Comment: Its surprising there are no examples or more details documentation on this.

Comment: @Marcin very true. Comparing the documentation with other services this service is really the least and really tuff to find things which you need. 

Thank you so much for taking our time out for this :)

Comment: No problem. Sorry, couldn't provide more useful details.

Comment: @Marcin no issues at all :)

Comment: @Marcin could you help me with this: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63917677/object-level-restriction-for-s3-with-iam-role