# Object level restriction for s3 with IAM Role

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I am trying to restrict user access at the object level in S3.

There are 2 folders in the s3 bucket. I am trying to give access to only one folder among the object.

The two folders are:

1. broker
2. carrier

This is the IAM Role policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::lodeobucket"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetObjectVersion",
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:DeleteObjectVersion"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::lodeobucket/broker/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

But the user is able to access the carrier folder as well.

Could anyone suggest what am I missing?

Comment: This is IAM policy, not bucket policy. So the user in question has this policy attached?

Comment: @Marcin yes this is IAM policy, Should i have any bucket policy as well?

Comment: By default bucket are private. So if the user has access to it, it means that there is some other policy that enables this. You could explicitly deny access to the folder if you want for that particular user.

Comment: @Marcin The user had only that policy attached to him.
But still, he is able to see the objects in 'carrier' folder

Comment: @Marcin I am looking for something where the person can't see any other folder than 'broker'. Is this possible?

Comment: @sumanthshetty What do you mean by "But the user is able to access the carrier folder as well"? Specifically, what do you mean by "access" -- do you mean List, or can they also Put and Get objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add the following conditon:

```
"Condition":{"StringLike":{"s3:prefix":["","broker/*"]}}
```

you user will not be able to enter carrier folder. It will still be visible in console. I don't think you can "hide" other folders, as this will break console access.

You can try the following policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::lodeobucket",
            "Condition":{"StringLike":{"s3:prefix":["","broker/*"]}}
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetObjectVersion",
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:DeleteObjectVersion"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::lodeobucket/broker/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: There is also an example policy for a similar usecase in the IAM docs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_examples_s3_home-directory-console.html

Comment: @Marcin, This is off topic but had to ask you. 

I am trying to design a code pipeline in Bahrain but it's unavailable in that region. 
Then thought of having code pipeline in another region till the code build part and will integrate code deploy from Bahrain. But codepipleline didn't gave an option to integrate it with code deploy in Bahrain.

IS there a way I can have a code pipeline to deploy on my EC2 machine which is in Bahrain?

Comment: @sumanthshetty CP can generally deploy to other regions. Maybe you set something wrong? You can make new question with relevant details about CP setup and your CodeDeploy in other region.